# HTML input maxlength Attribute issue with oppo F3 plus in chrome browser

Tags: html, validation

Facing issue in `chrome` browser in `OPPO F3 Plus` 
with `maxlength=100` in input type `text` but it's not exceeding beyond `63` characters.

**Device Name** : OPPO F3 Plus

**Browser** : Chrome v71

Example: `<input type="text" maxlength="100">`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your right arrow key in the input text to confirm because if 100 characters is more than the width of the input text u have to scroll to right to see the remaining characters.

Comment: sorry, but its just stopping to write. its not the case. Thanks.